# FileNotFoundError in "Python Crash Course"

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I've been using the "Python Crash Course" book to learn python. I'm currently on page 233-234 and can't seem to get the program to work. I'm supposed to import an image of a ship but every time that I try to do that using the line `self.image = pygame.image.load("images/Ship.bmp")` I get an error saying "FileNotFoundError: No file 'Ship.bmp' found in working directory. Where is my working directory and how do I get my file there? (using visual studious)

```
class Ship:

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_Rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/Ship.bmp")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

in a different class:

```
    self.ship = Ship(self)
```

Comment: The current working directory  (CWD) is an OS concept, there always is one, but it may **not** be where your `.py` file is. The best way to situations like this is to extract the directory from the path to your `.py` file which *is* stored in the predefined `__file__` variable and then use `os.path.join()` to create a full path to the image file — this will work regardless of what the current working directory is.

Comment: I edited the rest that would be needed

Comment: FYI, here's a Wikipedia article on the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). The OS associates one with each *process*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to determine an absolute path to the image file based on the location of your script file. Doing it this way will make your code work regardless of what the current working directory happens to be.

It uses the [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#concrete-paths) class in the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module to make things very simple (there's no need to use `os.path` to do things as I mentioned in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70557742/filenotfounderror-in-python-crash-course#comment124726973_70557742) — although it could also be done using it).

```
from pathlib import Path

class Ship:
    # Determine absolute path from relative path.
    image_path = Path(__file__).parent / "images/Ship.bmp"

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_Rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.image_path)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

print(Ship.image_path)  # -> Will show absolute path to image file.
```

I'm not sure what you meant about the "in a different class:" part (or even what the snippet of code shown below it is supposed to accomplish).